# Unity "initialization routine"

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am following a specific Unity tutorial and are told to put a specific line of code in one of my "scene initialization routines". Can anyone elaborate on what this means specifically? Where should I put this line.

Answer (score 1):

maybe he means before scene load?

if yes, try use `RuntimeInitializeOnLoadMethod` like this example

```
public class Main : MonoBehaviour
{
     // Runs before a scene gets loaded
     [RuntimeInitializeOnLoadMethod(RuntimeInitializeLoadType.BeforeSceneLoad)]
     public static void LoadMain()
     {
          // type your script here
     }
}
```